# Javascript code not running, how can I fix?

Tags: javascript

My code is supposed to add 1 to the counter when I hit space and then change the magnifying glass to tilt the other direction. It just doesn't do anything when I hit space.

I've fixed every problem I saw, nothing worked. Maybe somebody else knows, I'm really not that good at js.

```
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector( '.hits' );
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if( e.keyCode == 32 ) {
    addHit();
  }
}

var mag = "";
var hitElement2 = document.querySelector( '.mag' );
document.body.onkeydown = function(f) {
  if( f.keyCode == 32 ) {
    if( mag.text == "") {
        mag = "";
        renderMag();
    else
        mag = "";
        renderMag();
    }
  }
}

var addHit = function() {
  hits++;
  renderHits();
}

var renderMag = function() {
  hitElement2.innerHTML = mag;
}

var renderHits = function() {
  hitElement.innerHTML = hits;
}

var resetHits = function() {
  hits = 0;
  renderHits();
}
```

Console says absolutely nothing too.

Comment: So did you add console.log statements to see where it fails?

Comment: There are many, many problems with this code. Here are a couple: 1) you can only set one listener on an event property such as `.onkeydown`. You've overwritten the first with the second. You should use `.addEventListener()`. 2) You set a variable `mag` as a string, then a few lines later you use that same variable as if it were an object: `if(mag.text ==...)`. That won't work. Have another go at it and see what you can do.

Comment: @epascarello I did, nothing showed up in console, even when I put it at the begining of the script.

Comment: The if-else block doesn't have parentheses closed properly. Please have a look.
`if( mag.text == "") {
   mag = "";
}
else
    mag = "";
}
    renderMag();`

Comment: How is this script loaded into your page?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a few things and changed a few things that didn't need fixing. The three key points:

- As mentioned, if a bit harshly, by Randy, your second event listener was overwriting your first, so hits was not increasing
- The brackets in the if statement of your second event listener had some issues
- Though checking the mag icon might work, using icons in the code feels like asking for something to break, so I changed that to a modulo check, to see whether hits was odd or even.

You were on the right track. When you have issues like this in the future, try putting console log statements in various places in the code. Make predictions about what variables should have what values at what points, then check if they do, then, if they don't, try to figure out why not.

```js
var hits = 0;
var hitElement = document.querySelector('.hits');

var mag = "";
var hitElement2 = document.querySelector('.mag');
document.body.onkeydown = function(f) {
  if (f.key == ' ') {
    addHit();
    if (hits % 2 === 0) {
      mag = "";
      renderMag();
    } else {
      mag = "";
      renderMag();
    }
  }
}

function addHit() {
  hits++;
  renderHits();
}

function renderMag() {
  hitElement2.innerHTML = mag;
}



function renderHits() {
  hitElement.innerHTML = hits;
}

function resetHits() {
  hits = 0;
  renderHits();
}
```

```html
<div class="hits"></div>
<div class="mag"></div>
```